# Can't include Flowbite React Theme on Sidebar

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, flowbite

Currently I'm learning react and want to use Flowbite components. The first thing I want to use is a sidebar. In my Sidebar.tsx file I have the following theme and sidebar:
Theme(This is the exact same as it was in the flowbite documentation sidebar page):

```
const ownTheme : FlowbiteSidebarTheme ={
    "root": {
        "base": "h-full",
        "collapsed": {
            "on": "w-16",
            "off": "w-64"
        },
        "inner": "h-full overflow-y-auto overflow-x-hidden rounded bg-gray-50 py-4 px-3 dark:bg-gray-800"
    },
    "collapse": {
        "button": "group flex w-full items-center rounded-lg p-2 text-base font-normal text-gray-900 transition duration-75 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700",
        "icon": {
            "base": "h-6 w-6 text-gray-500 transition duration-75 group-hover:text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-400 dark:group-hover:text-white",
            "open": {
                "off": "",
                "on": "text-gray-900"
            }
        },
        "label": {
            "base": "ml-3 flex-1 whitespace-nowrap text-left",
            "icon": {
                "base": "h-6 w-6 transition ease-in-out delay-0",
                "open": {
                    "on": "rotate-180",
                    "off": ""
                }
            }
        },
        "list": "space-y-2 py-2"
    },
    "cta": {
        "base": "mt-6 rounded-lg p-4 bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-700",
        "color": {
            "blue": "bg-cyan-50 dark:bg-cyan-900",
            "dark": "bg-dark-50 dark:bg-dark-900",
            "failure": "bg-red-50 dark:bg-red-900",
            "gray": "bg-alternative-50 dark:bg-alternative-900",
            "green": "bg-green-50 dark:bg-green-900",
            "light": "bg-light-50 dark:bg-light-900",
            "red": "bg-red-50 dark:bg-red-900",
            "purple": "bg-purple-50 dark:bg-purple-900",
            "success": "bg-green-50 dark:bg-green-900",
            "yellow": "bg-yellow-50 dark:bg-yellow-900",
            "warning": "bg-yellow-50 dark:bg-yellow-900"
        }
    },
    "item": {
        "base": "flex items-center justify-center rounded-lg p-2 text-base font-normal text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700",
        "active": "bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-700",
        "collapsed": {
            "insideCollapse": "group w-full pl-8 transition duration-75",
            "noIcon": "font-bold"
        },
        "content": {
            "base": "px-3 flex-1 whitespace-nowrap"
        },
        "icon": {
            "base": "h-6 w-6 flex-shrink-0 text-gray-500 transition duration-75 group-hover:text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-400 dark:group-hover:text-white",
            "active": "text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-100"
        },
        "label": "",
        "listItem": ""
    },
    "items": {
        "base": ""
    },
    "itemGroup": {
        "base": "mt-4 space-y-2 border-t border-gray-200 pt-4 first:mt-0 first:border-t-0 first:pt-0 dark:border-gray-700"
    },
    "logo": {
        "base": "mb-5 flex items-center pl-2.5",
        "collapsed": {
            "on": "hidden",
            "off": "self-center whitespace-nowrap text-xl font-semibold dark:text-white"
        },
        "img": "mr-3 h-6 sm:h-7"
    }
};
```

This is my react component:

```
function Side(){

    return (

        <Sidebar theme={ownTheme}>
            <Sidebar.Items>
                <Sidebar.ItemGroup>
                    <Sidebar.Item href={<MainPage/>} >
                        Main
                    </Sidebar.Item>
                    <Sidebar.Item href="#">
                        Sign In
                    </Sidebar.Item>
                    <Sidebar.Item href="#">
                        Sign Up
                    </Sidebar.Item>
                </Sidebar.ItemGroup>
            </Sidebar.Items>
        </Sidebar>
    );
}

export default Side;
```

I tried the method with **CustomFlowbiteTheme** and [flowbite](/questions/tagged/flowbite) tag with theme but that didn't worked for me too.

This is my tailwind config:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{html,js,tsx} ','./node_modules/flowbite/**/*.{js,tsx,ts}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [require('flowbite/plugin')],
}
```

My sidebar looks like this:
[The sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFvBk.png)

Can someone please explain to me what do I have to do to make the Style work?

I have installed every dependency like tailwind css and flowbite and flowbite-react.

Comment: Consider checking you have `import`ed the CSS that contains the `@tailwind` statements somewhere in the "main" app code.

Comment: It's working finally. You got it right I didn't knew about you need one css for everything. I tried to use multiple css that was the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add this Tags:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Inside the index.css file or main css file.

I try to replicate your scenario to fix it. This is the fixed code:

https://github.com/pablosalazzar/stackoverflow-answer-3

Also I use this guide to setup the tailwind and Flowbite stuff : https://flowbite.com/docs/getting-started/react/